# Keyboard suddenly starts to randomly skip letters

Tags: keyboard, hardware-failure

I have an Asus (K52Jr) laptop for almost 4 years now. I'm working from home for almost 3 years so I use the laptop extensively.

I never had a problem with the keyboard, but, suddenly yesterday it started skipping random letters. It seems improbable for me to be because of dust or something like that because it wasn't a process in which letter by letter the keys stopped working, instead it affects all the keys all of the sudden. For about 2 hours last night it worked well again, but this morning started acting strange again.

So, today I removed my keyboard and cleaned it thoroughly. It didn't help. It still skips letters. And I noticed something else today, also. If I keep a key pressed from time to time, while repeating the key, it stops a little, like I would lift my finger up and push the key again.

I can't understand what's going on. Could it be something with the data cable? When I cleaned the keyboard today I plugged out the data cable also (in case something wasn't plugged in correctly).

I also booted in Safe Mode, to see if it's a software problem, but the same issue occurred in safe mode also (even in the "Repair mode with command prompt")

Comment: Does the same issue continue with an external keyboard?

Comment: I don't have one right now to test, but I will buy one in a few hours to check.

Comment: I mean, the machine is now 'old' so I would hope the new keyboard works so you can still use it... The only other thing to possibly do is a system restore, but I would guess it's a hardware issue.

Comment: I also believe it to be a hardware issue. I will probably use an external keyboard for now, and later on I will buy a new keyboard (until today I didn't even know one can buy laptop keyboards separately).

Comment: You can buy laptop keyboards (see manufacturers website usually) but, it may not be the keyboard itself that is faulty (it could be wiring else where)

Comment: Oh, thanks @DaveRook, I didn't think of that possibility. I'll have to check that somehow. The thing is the laptop was maintained well and it's in good condition, although it has its years, so I would try to fix this problem if possible. Thanks again

Comment: @DaveRook - thanks for your comments - I managed to fix the keyboard. When you said `but, it may not be the keyboard itself that is faulty (it could be wiring else where)` it got me thinking. It wasn't from the keyboard after all. My battery was slowly failing for a few months now, and yesterday windows started telling me that it can't detect the battery at all. I didn't made the connection until now, so I pulled out the battery and the keyboard is working now properly. Amazing, right? :)

Comment: Well done, but please do answer your own question as it may be useful for others in the future to see things like this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the problem. It wasn't the keyboard at all.

The battery I was using on my laptop started failing slowly a few months back, and it seems yesterday it was its last day (because Windows stared telling me that there is no battery detected even if the battery was plugged in).

I unplugged the battery and everything works fine now. Strange? Yeah. But it works :)

Comment: Yeah, sometimes these things appear totally unrelated. In my old job we had a Dell or HP laptop come in as it was working really slowly and wasn't booting up to windows (can't remember which). It sat on the side for a good hour on the loading screen. We happened to disconnect the charger from the machine (so it was running on battery) and it immediately booted. Turns out the smart pin on the charger was damaged and it was affecting the speed of the PC, strange eh?

Comment: @JoeHarper yep, strange things happen in the world of computers :)

Comment: Good information regarding solution for fixing this intermittent malfunction, as such malfunctions can also be caused by intermittent connector contact, etc, and helpful for Asker to post the solution. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows ,

- Please go to device manager and uninstall keyboard driver then restart the windows.
- If you installed crazy software recently uninstall it.
- Back up your data and Re-install the windows If problem persists , do bios update.
  the instructions of Asus  before doing bios update because if you make mistake you can
  damage the motherboard.
- Remove the battery see if problem persists

**Buy an External Keyboard** , if you don't want to send the machine to a service center.

Have a nice day

Answer (score -1):

I have an N56J Asus laptop and the same thing happened to me. It's only because of a dead battery so don't waste your money buying a new keyboard or... .
Just remove the battery!